# How to set default height of the UILabel in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set the (no text) height like the UIlabel have a line text 's height

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Comment: what do you mean by default height ? It depends on the label frame and font size!!!!!

Comment: By setting its height constraint?

Comment: i use autolayout when the label is empty and not set the height, the label 's height is 0.  I want to know how to set the default height that text is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AutoLayout:
add a constraint of height to the label!
With no AutoLayout:
set the frame will work!

Answer (score 0):

Use autolayout constraints. simply put a constraint on height but make sure to put other constraints too else constraint bugs will occur. to check thatits occuring...set the background color to grey and you will see the results.